# Why was "fundamental group intuition" deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-accounts

I'm just wondering why [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93594/fundamental-group-intuition) called "fundamental group intuition" was deleted.

I'm new to this site, and this was the first question I answered; I was a bit confused to log in this morning to be told that I had 51 reputation but had never posted anything.

It seems that the user who posted this question deleted their account -- but other questions they asked haven't been deleted (eg [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87529/topology-on-n-colorings-of-a-lattice)), so I guess questions aren't automatically deleted when the OP closes their account.

But it seems from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) that a user shouldn't be able to delete their own question if there is an answer with upvotes.

I'm not concerned about my answer no longer existing, I'm just trying to figure out how this site works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a "feature" related to deleting user accounts.  When an account is deleted, all of the posts, questions and answers, that have a negative net vote count are automatically deleted.  In the case of questions, this happens regardless of the vote counts of the answers.

Because your answer deserves to be brought back, I just cast a vote to undelete.  If 2 more 10k+ users or one moderator votes to undelete, it will be back.

**Update**: It is back.

<strike>P.S.: Do not do a reputation recalc too soon, or you will lose the ability to comment on all posts.</strike>

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure how this happened. [An account that has posted a question cannot be deleted by the user themselves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account), and since Adina's answer was voted up, [the user would not have been able to delete their question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/161783) and then proceed to delete their account. Reviewing the moderator activity, I don't see that any of us deleted an account within the past day, or interacted at all with user 13255 or question 93594 (that includes both math.SE moderators and "global" StackExchange moderators).

Also, this user still exists on other SE sites. Whatever happened was math.SE-specific.

---

**Update:** The user informs me that they requested their account be deleted in the manner described in my first link above. I guess it just the case that such deletions are done in a way that doesn't appear as a moderator action on the site.

Comment: Is your ability to review moderator activity limited to the moderators specific to this site, i.e., the ones listed at http://math.stackexchange.com/about?

Comment: We are able to see all moderator activity on the site including StackExchange employees.

Comment: Interesting.  Hopefully someone will reveal, at least to our moderators, what exactly happened.

Comment: @Zev The dashboard doesn't show SE employees as active in all cases, just deleting a user doesn't seem to cause them to appear. If you go to the "all" timeframe and check the mods individually you might be able to see the deletion of the user.

Comment: @Fabian: Aha, I see you're absolutely right! I can see the deletion of the user now. Thank you for the explanation.